# I am looking for Thermal IR Photography with 1 m resolution?

Tags: data, remote-sensing, imagery

I am looking for thermal IR photography with 1m resolution?

It needs to be recent or maybe a company in western Canada that can fly a mission like this. Satellite or flown photos both work, I am just looking for sources and maybe the specific satellites to look for.

Comment: Pretty sure that's going to have to be aircraft flown. I'm not aware of any satellite based thermal sensor with that kind of resolution. [WorldView-3](http://www.satimagingcorp.com/satellite-sensors/worldview-3/) was launched last year and is 3.7m for shortwave infrared. By contrast, most other sensors I'm aware of are 20-60m for thermal.

Comment: I agree. Infrared is longwave IR and so low-energy that it just can't have as good resolution as shortwave channels. Means that 1 m thermal must be acquired from pretty close altitude. I suppose that only night time acquisition gives real advantage because sunny and shadowed areas would give a huge noise at daytime. Thus, a special mission because night time is not so good for visible channels.